# How to make a Plotly plot follow the parent container's size?

Tags: javascript, css, plotly, plotly.js

Here the resizing of the image happens automatically when you resize the parent `div`. **How to make a similar behaviour for the Plotly plot, with high FPS?**

```js
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', [{x: [1, 2, 3, 4], y: [10, 15, 13, 17], mode: 'markers'}], {margin: {l: 50, r: 50, b: 50, t: 50, pad: 4}});
```

```css
#a, #b { border: 1px solid black; resize: both; overflow: auto; height: 150px; width: 150px; }
#a img { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.16.2.min.js"></script>
<div id="a"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/240/200"></div>
<div id="b"><div id="myDiv"></div></div>
```

---

Edit: With the current answer, it also becomes slow with a big plot:

```js
var z = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) 
    z.push(Array.from({length: 600}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)));  
var data = [{z: z, colorscale: 'YlGnBu', type: 'heatmap'}];
Plotly.newPlot('b', data, {margin: {l: 50, r: 50, b: 50, t: 50, pad: 4}});
function fixer() {
    el = document.getElementById('b');
    Plotly.newPlot(el, el.data, el.layout, {responsive: true});
}
setTimeout(function() {
    el = document.getElementById('b');
    new ResizeSensor(el, fixer)
}, 200);
```

```css
#a, #b { 
border: 1px solid black; 
resize: both; 
overflow: auto;
height: 150px; 
width: 150px; }
#a img { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.16.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/css-element-queries/1.2.3/ResizeSensor.js"></script>
<div id="a"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/240/200"></div>
<div id="b" onresize=fixer></div>
```

Click on the image to see a video screencast:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

#### Updated

Based on your comments that your actual data is far more extensive than in your question, I brought in some data from a Plotly example for scatter3d--- just with the purpose of *slowing it down*. Wow, what a difference.

Initially, I wrote (less the misspelled words, sigh):

> Since resizing is only detectable at the window level, you need an intervention. This brings in ResizeSensor.js. I'm not the most JS-savvy, so you could probably streamline this further.
> I've added some script: the function fixer re-plots the graph when the container is resized. Additionally, instead of `myDiv`, I've got the Plotly graph in `b`.
> The only changes are in `<!-- language: lang-html -->`

I've changed the data and plot creation, adding `responsive: true` to the configuration at the onset. Additionally, I've changed `fixer` to `Plotly.react` instead of `Plotly.newPlot`. The responsive difference with the data I used here is significant.

Let me know if this is what you're looking for. If it's still really slow on your end let me know if there was any improvement.

```js
d3.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/3d-scatter.csv', function(err, rows){
function unpack(rows, key) {
return rows.map(function(row)
{ return row[key]; });}

var trace1 = {
x:unpack(rows, 'x1'), y: unpack(rows, 'y1'), z: unpack(rows, 'z1'),
mode: 'markers',
marker: {
    size: 12,
    line: {
    color: 'rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.14)',
    width: 0.5},
    opacity: 0.8},
type: 'scatter3d'
};

var trace2 = {
x:unpack(rows, 'x2'), y: unpack(rows, 'y2'), z: unpack(rows, 'z2'),
mode: 'markers',
marker: {
    color: 'rgb(127, 127, 127)',
    size: 12,
    symbol: 'circle',
    line: {
    color: 'rgb(204, 204, 204)',
    width: 1},
    opacity: 0.8},
type: 'scatter3d'};

var data = [trace1, trace2];
var layout = {margin: {
l: 0,
r: 0,
b: 0,
t: 0
  }};
Plotly.newPlot('b', data, layout, {responsive: true});
});
```

```css
#a, #b { 
border: 1px solid black; 
resize: both; 
overflow: auto;
height: 150px; 
width: 150px; }
#a img { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.16.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/css-element-queries/1.2.3/ResizeSensor.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js'></script>
<script>
function fixer() {
  el = document.getElementById('b');
  Plotly.react(el, el.data, el.layout, {responsive: true});
}
setTimeout(function() {
  el = document.getElementById('b');
  new ResizeSensor(el, fixer);
}, 200);
</script>
<div id="a"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/240/200"></div>
<div id="b" onresize=fixer></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When the data has more than hundreds of points, it is quite slow, see the snippet in the "Edit" part of my question. Do you have any idea @Kat?

Comment: See https://i.imgur.com/EjNOZEB.mp4 @Kat.

Comment: I've made an update. Read through it and let me know.

Comment: Thanks @Kat, I'll study this in my use case, and I'll report how it works! Thanks again!